# Sumarizar campos com cálculos direto na consulta sql

Tags: sql, firebird

Não sei como fazer isso tentei quase que o dia inteiro e não consegui se alguma poder ajudar...

O Problema é tenho que somar um campo que está seno calculado na direto da consulta sql.

**Sql:**

```
SELECT
 CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTE,
 CLIENTES.CLIENTE,
 SUM(DAV_ITENS.QUANTIDADE) AS QUANTIDADES,
 SUM(DAV_ITENS.VALOR_CUSTO * DAV_ITENS.QUANTIDADE) AS VALOR_CUSTO,
 SUM(DAV_ITENS.VALOR_TOTAL) AS VALOR_TOTAL
FROM DAV
 LEFT OUTER JOIN DAV_ITENS ON (DAV.ID = DAV_ITENS.ID_DAV)
 INNER JOIN CLIENTES ON (CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTE = DAV.ID_CLIENTE)
GROUP BY
 CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTE,
 CLIENTES.CLIENTE, 
 DAV_ITENS.QUANTIDADE,
 DAV_ITENS.VALOR_CUSTO,
 DAV_ITENS.VALOR_TOTAL
```

O proposito dessa consulta é somar todos o preço de custo de todos os produtos que um cliente comprou. Só que ele não está fazendo isso.

[image: Esse é o resultado da consulta SQL]

o que eu preciso é:

Ex: Cliente 76 tem uma compra com dois produtos destintos e para cada uma eles compra três unidades de uma mesmo item o primeiro item a soma da 26,64 e do segundo 334,80 só que eu preciso que ele some esses dois valores para que a linha da fique assim?

```
| id |            nome | QUANT | VALOR_CUSTO  | VALOR_VENDA  |
|----|-----------------|-------|--------------|--------------|
| 76 |         Eduardo |     6 |       364.44 |          873 |
| 20 |         Janaína |   4.2 |           11 |        138,6 |
| 10 |         Zé lelé | 40.25 |            5 |       603,75 |
```

Comment: Você não deve colocar na cláusula GROUP BY os campos que estão nas funções de agregação. Retire os campos DAV_ITENS.QUANTIDADE, DAV_ITENS.VALOR_CUSTO e DAV_ITENS.VALOR_TOTAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sql:**

```
SELECT
 CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTE,
 CLIENTES.CLIENTE,
 SUM(DAV_ITENS.QUANTIDADE) AS QUANTIDADES,
 SUM(DAV_ITENS.VALOR_CUSTO * DAV_ITENS.QUANTIDADE) AS VALOR_CUSTO,
 SUM(DAV_ITENS.VALOR_TOTAL) AS VALOR_TOTAL
FROM DAV
 LEFT OUTER JOIN DAV_ITENS ON (DAV.ID = DAV_ITENS.ID_DAV)
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN PRODUTOS ON (DAV_ITENS.ID_PRODUTO = PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO)
 INNER JOIN CLIENTES ON (CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTE = DAV.ID_CLIENTE)
GROUP BY
 CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTE,
 CLIENTES.CLIENTE
```

No seu caso você não deve acrescentar os campos `DAV_ITENS.QUANTIDADE, DAV_ITENS.VALOR_CUSTO, DAV_ITENS.VALOR_TOTAL`, pois estes campo serão utilizados na função `SUM()`, pois utilizando o `GROUP BY` serão agrupado por valores em comum. 
Como os campos `DAV_ITENS.QUANTIDADE, DAV_ITENS.VALOR_CUSTO, DAV_ITENS.VALOR_TOTAL` tem valores distinto ele não fazia a soma correta.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ficou muito bom valeu!